# Keep sorted extendedDataTable richfaces after a refresh

Tags: sorting, jsf, richfaces

I am working with richfaces, I have a `extendedDataTable` table, after displaying lines in table, I do a sort. After that I do a `onRowDblClick` to show more information. Then my problem is when I do a back to principal table, the table is not sorted. My questions are:

1. where richfaces do the sort;
2. is it possible to sort list in server side when table is sorted in client side;
3. is it possible to keep the sorted list in array in Java script.

   ```
    <rich:extendedDataTable id="EnteterecpGlo" value="#{EnteteReceptionsGlobale.enteteReceptions}" var="receptionList" sortMode="single" rowKeyVar="rkv" style="align:left;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;" width="100%" height="365" rows="16" selectionMode="single" onRowDblClick="if(#{receptionList.numintrec}!='undefined') {rechercherdetail(#{receptionList.numintrec}); }" enableContextMenu="true">
               <rich:column width="8%"   sortBy="#{receptionList.selection}">
                 <center>
                   <f:facet name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_id_select" value="Selection" />
                   </f:facet>                  
                   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="takeselection(#{receptionList.numintrec})" value="#{receptionList.selection}"  >
                   </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                                
                 </center>  
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_cod_ext_rec_vgr"  width="8%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.numextrec}" label="N&#186; reception "  >

                   <f:facet id="id_fac_cod_ext_rec_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_cod_ext_rec_vgr" value="N&#186; Recep">                              
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_cod_ext_rec_vgr" value="N&#186; Reception"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="copt_cod_ext_rec_vgr" value="#{receptionList.numextrec}" />
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_num_com_vgr"  width="8%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.numcommande}" label="N&#186; Commande" >
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_num_com_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_num_com_vgr" value="N&#186; Cmde" >                              
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_num_com_vgr" value="N&#186; Commande"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_num_com_vgr" value="#{receptionList.numcommande}" >                           
                   </h:outputText>
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_bl_vgr"  width="7%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.numbonliv}" label="N&#186; BL" >
                   <f:facet id="id_fac_bl_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_bl_vgr" value="N&#186; BL" >                             
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_bl_vgr" value="N&#186; Bon de Livraison"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="copt_bl_vgr" value="#{receptionList.numbonliv}" />
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_site_vgr"  width="4%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.site}" label="Site">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_site_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_site_vgr" value="Site" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_site_vgr" value="#{receptionList.site}" />
               </rich:column>      


               <rich:column id="id_col_libsite_vgr"  width="17%" 
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.libsite}" label="Libelle">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_libsite_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_libsite_vgr" value="Libelle" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_libsite_vgr" value="#{receptionList.libsite}" />
               </rich:column>      


               <rich:column id="id_col_etatfac_vgr"  width="8%" 
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.etatfacture}" label="Etat Facture">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_etatfac_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_etatfac_vgr" value="Etat Facture" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_etatfac_vgr" value="#{receptionList.etatfacture}" />
               </rich:column>  

               <rich:column id="id_col_numtraite_vgr"  width="10%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.numtraite}" label="N&#186; Reglement">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_numtraite_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_numtraite_vgr" value="N&#186; Reglement" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_numtraite_vgr" value="#{receptionList.numtraite}" />
               </rich:column>      

               <rich:column id="id_col_daterec_vgr"  width="8%" 
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.datereception}" label="Date Reception">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_daterec_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_daterec_vgr" value="Date Recep" >                                
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_daterec_vgr" value="Date Reception"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_daterec_vgr" value="#{receptionList.datereception}" >
                   <f:convertDateTime id="fcvt_daterec_vgr" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                   </h:outputText>
               </rich:column>      

               <rich:column id="id_col_datecmd_vgr"  width="8%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.datecommande}" label="Date Commande">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_datecmd_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_datecmd_vgr" value="Date Cmde" >                             
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_datecmd_vgr" value="Date Commande"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_datecmd_vgr" value="#{receptionList.datecommande}" >
                   <f:convertDateTime id="fcvt_datecmd_vgr" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                   </h:outputText>
               </rich:column>      

               <rich:column id="id_col_ville_vgr"  width="10%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.ville}" label="ville">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_ville_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_ville_vgr" value="ville" />
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_ville_vgr" value="#{receptionList.ville}" />
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_concom_vgr"  width="6%"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.contracommercial}" label="Contrat Commercial">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_concom_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_concom_vgr" value="Contrat" >                                
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_concom_vgr" value="Contrat Commercial"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_concom_vgr" value="#{receptionList.contracommercial}" />                  
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_codefrs_concom_vgr" width="10%"   rendered="#{Login.userprofil==0}"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.codefrs}" label="Code Fourn">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_codefrs_concom_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_codefrs_concom_vgr" value="Code Fourn" >                             
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_codefrs_concom_vgr" value="Code Fournisseur"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_codefrs_concom_vgr" value="#{receptionList.codefrs}" />
               </rich:column>

               <rich:column id="id_col_libfrs_concom_vgr" width="10%"  rendered="#{Login.userprofil==0}"
                   sortBy="#{receptionList.libfrs}" label="Lib Fourn">
                   <f:facet id="fid_fac_libfrs_concom_vgr" name="header">
                       <h:outputText id="fopt_libfrs_concom_vgr" value="Lib Fourn" >                               
                           <rich:toolTip for="fopt_libfrs_concom_vgr" value="Libelle Fournisseur"/>
                       </h:outputText>
                   </f:facet>
                   <h:outputText id="opt_libfrs_concom_vgr" value="#{receptionList.libfrs}" />
               </rich:column>                                                              
   </rich:extendedDataTable>
   ```

Comment: What version of richfaces are your using?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tableState` attribute of your datatable to persist the state of the table in your backing bean. So what you'll have is:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="EnteterecpGlo" value="#{EnteteReceptionsGlobale.enteteReceptions}" var="receptionList" tableState="#{EnteteReceptionsGlobale.savedState}" sortMode="single"
```

`savedState` should correspond to a `String` backing bean variable. Obviously for this to work, the variable must be persisted in a durable source, so definitely NOT a `@RequestScoped` bean